# order by clause in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

I am writing a sql to get the medium of a list of numbers (assume the length of the list is odd)

`set @r=0;
select S.num
from
(select num, case when num is not NULL then (@r:=@r+1) end as rowIndex
from T1
order by num) S
where rowIndex = ceil(@r/2)`

This query works, however, I am confused by my subquery. My question is the following: if I simply type

`select num, case when num is not NULL then (@r:=@r+1) end as rowIndex
from T1`

I will have 2 columns with the 1st column being the original list of numbers in its original order, e.g., 10,1,3,11,5,4,19... and the 2nd column is the row index, 1,2,3,4,.... Note that what I want is first sort my original list in ascending order, then give each row its row index.

I initially thought that

`select num, case when num is not NULL then (@r:=@r+1) end as rowIndex
from T1
order by num`

will produce a table such that the 1st column is the sorted version of my original list, but then 2nd column is a rearrangement of the index set [1,2,3,...]. Because I think the order of the query is: first create a table as suggested by `select num, case when num is not NULL then (@r:=@r+1) end as rowIndex from T1`, then it sorts this table by `num` column, and hence, when `num` column is sorted, the `rowIndex` column should no longer be [1,2,3,...].

But actually, it seems that it first just sort the `num` column and then it add row index. In another word, I find that whether I add `order by num` or not, the 2nd column will always be a nice row index [1,2,3,4,...]. Why?

Comment: Can you add a tabular data example because now it is really hard to follow what you are talking about

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen sorry, I was just about to do that, @Used_By_Already has made a table in the answer below. But I still feel confused about this `order by` clause in Mysql

Answer (score 1):

The derived table (subquery) orders your `num` column and gives each row an index number according to that order. The outer query then re-uses the computed vale of @r to arrive at the half-way point (median) in that ordered series.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(
>    num NUMERIC(6,2)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable(num) VALUES (12.4);
> INSERT INTO mytable(num) VALUES (134.9);
> INSERT INTO mytable(num) VALUES (45.12);
> INSERT INTO mytable(num) VALUES (876.78);
> INSERT INTO mytable(num) VALUES (212.8);
> INSERT INTO mytable(num) VALUES (578.9);
> ```

> ```
> set @r=0;
> select num, case when num is not NULL then (@r:=@r+1) end as rowIndex
> from mytable T1
> order by num;
> ```
>
> ```
>    num | rowIndex
> -----: | -------:
>  12.40 |        1
>  45.12 |        2
> 134.90 |        3
> 212.80 |        4
> 578.90 |        5
> 876.78 |        6
> ```

> ```
> set @r=0;
> select S.num
> from (
>     select num, case when num is not NULL then (@r:=@r+1) end as rowIndex
>     from mytable T1
>     order by num
>     ) S
> where rowIndex = ceil(@r/2);
> ```
>
> ```
> |    num |
> | -----: |
> | 134.90 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=c459ed49fdf8fe57d5c94e0a1960c8d1)*

If we remove the order by however **the results are not predictable**. e.g.

> ```
> set @r=0;
> select num, case when num is not NULL then (@r:=@r+1) end as rowIndex
> from mytable T1
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
>    num | rowIndex
> -----: | -------:
>  12.40 |        1
> 134.90 |        2
>  45.12 |        3
> 876.78 |        4
> 212.80 |        5
> 578.90 |        6
> ```

> ```
> set @r=0;
> select S.num
> from (
>     select num, case when num is not NULL then (@r:=@r+1) end as rowIndex
>     from mytable T1
>     ) S
> where rowIndex = ceil(@r/2);
> ```
>
> ```
> |   num |
> | ----: |
> | 45.12 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6e0c6ed2fc3a904fe04cd6d9f6aaaf0b)*

Without an explicit ORDER BY clause it is NOT safe to assume the number series will be ordered as you need it. It might occur, but you cannot rely on it.

Comment: Thanks! But what makes me feel really puzzled is I thought `select num, @r:=@r+1 end as rowIndex from mytable T1 order by num` would give me the 2nd column `1,3,2,5,6,4`. But it gives `1,2,3,4,5,6`. I mean if you just execute `select num, @r:=@r+1 end as rowIndex
from mytable T1`, i.e., without `order by num`, the 2nd column of the output would still be `1,2,3,4,5,6` right?, then I consider an extra `order by` is an operation on the derived table, so shouldn't the 2nd column `1,2,3,4,5,6` be also reordered according to the order of the `num` column?

Comment: *"would give me the 2nd column 1,3,2,5,6,4."*  No, it would not. If it did it would be completely useless in ariving at the midpoint. Using those variables IS AFFECTED by the order by. - thankfully.

Comment: I know, but I was wondering the sequence of generating new tables in sql. So `select num, @r:=@r+1 end as rowIndex from mytable` should generate a table with 2 colums and such that the 1st column is an unsorted list of numbers and the 2nd column is `1,2,3,4,5,6` right? Then let's call this table `T2`, it should be stored in memory right? Then the operation `order by num`, should rearrange the rows of table `T2` shouldn't it? Then why this rearrangement does not affect the 2nd column in `T2`?

Comment: Your assumptions about the sequence of operations is incorrect, MySQL "knows" that the query is combining variable manipulation and **order by** so it deliberately applying the order THEN calculating the variables and returning the resultset, which the outer query then uses. The empirical evidence is in front of you.

Comment: I see. But what if I just want the newly created 2nd column to be rearranged based on the sorted order of the 1st column (completely independent of this post), then how should MySQL solves this problem?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. The second column (calculated variables) IS ALREADY based on the SORTED ORDER of the 1st column (table data). So to me you just asked: why is the sky blue given that the sky is blue.

Comment: I guess I didn't express it clear. Say I am an insurance firm and I receive one claim each month, whose value happens to be `num = [12,134,45,876,212,578]`. The discount factor is 1.05 per month, then `set @r=1;select num, @r:=@r*1.05 as factor from mytable` Then the 2nd column of the generated table, denoted by `T2`, is `1.05, 1.1,1.16,1.21,1.28,1.34`. Now I want to see the `num` being sorted in ascending order and I also want to see its corresponding factor. Now if I do `select * from T2 order by num`, I will get the desired answer with the 2nd column `1.05,1.16,1.1,1.28,1.34,1.21`.

Comment: But if I do them in one query without actually generate the intermediate table `T2`, i.e., `set @r=1;select num, @r:=@r*1.05 as factor from mytable order by num`, then I will get 1st column being `12,45,134,212,578,876` but the 2nd column (`factor`) being `1.05, 1.1,1.16,1.21,1.28,1.34`. In this case, the `factor` column does not correspond to the 1st column

Comment: Can you add to the question please, comments just don't allow for sufficient formatting. **In reality it's probably a completely new question and this one should be closed off.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148367/discussion-between-used-by-already-and-ftxx).